# Get Selected First Column Value of Selected Row

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selecteditem

i have a listview with multicolumn declare in this mode:

```
 <ListView Grid.Column="1" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,449,0,0" Name="lstFilesInFolder" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="453" SelectionChanged="lstFilesInFolder_SelectionChanged" MouseDoubleClick="lstFilesInFolder_MouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" Color="Black" Opacity="1"></DropShadowEffect>
        </ListView.Effect>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}" Width="325" Header="File Path" />
                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}" Width="100" Header="Code" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I add the element programmatically in this mode:

```
 lstFilesInFolder.Items.Add(new { Path = listFiles[i] });
```

and it's function correcly.
But i want to retrieve the path of selected item of listview? I've read more article and post but i don't know how to retrieve the element.
Please help me!

News:

If I try this code i received my data of selected Row:

```
ItemCollection listitem = lstFilesInFolder.Items;
        List lst = new List();
        MessageBox.Show(listitem.GetItemAt(lstFilesInFolder.SelectedIndex).ToString());
```

Now i want retrieve only first column.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for sure, if this is what you really want ...

```
for (int conditionVar = 0; conditionVar < listView1.Items.Count; conditionVar++)
{
   String firstValue =  listView1.Items[conditionVar].Text.ToString();
   String secondValue = listView1.Items[conditionVar].SubItems[1].Text.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample `listView`

[image]

if you want to get the `First Value`. Do it like this:

```
string item = lstFilesInFolder.Items[lstFilesInFolder.FocusedItem.Index].Text;
```

but if you want the second value, you need to specify its `SubItem`

```
string item = 
   lstFilesInFolder.Items[lstFilesInFolder.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[1].Text;
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' doesn't contain definition of 'FocusedItem'

Comment: oh its wpf, im sorry i didn't see that. i'll just update my answer. :)